# jquery . Fast image slide on IE

Tags: jquery, image, performance, slide

I am try to do something like video manyal on how to use some pages on my website. 
with vector editor i have made step by step pictures and want to show tham realy fast each after other to something like gif file.

Using jquery hide and show methods.

```
$(firstimage).hide();
$(secondimage).show();
```

it works fine on chrome nad firefox but ie make it slower and blicks.
i have try to preload images to chache but no luck.

mybe someone done it before?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. 
Option one is to create absolute positioned divs for each image and cycle through them with the click event.

Option two is to cycle through each image using the click event.

Option one:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="image-1" class="images">
        <img src="path/some_image-0.gif" width="150" />
    </div>
    <div id="image-2" class="images">
        <img src="path/some_image-1.gif" width="150" />
    </div>
     <div id="image-3" class="images">
        <img src="path/some_image-2.gif" width="150" />
    </div>
    <div id="image-4" class="images">
        <img src="path/some_image-3.gif" width="150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}

.images {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var total_images = 4; // Set this variable to total number of images
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.images').hide();
   $('#image-1').show();
   $('.images').click(function() {
       var current_img = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]); // get current file number
       var new_img = current_img+1; // Increment current image number by one
       $('#image-' + current_img).hide();
       if(new_img > total_images){  // check if total has been reached
          new_img = 1;
       }
       $('#image-' + new_img).show(); // set new image source
  });
});
```

this option will be faster as you don't have to wait to load the image.
Here is the JSFiddle for this option: http://jsfiddle.net/xsCVY/1/

Option two:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="/path/some_image-0.gif" class="images" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var total_images = 3; // Set this variable to total number of images
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.images').click(function() {
            var current_img = parseInt($(this).attr('src').split('-')[1]); // get current file number
            var new_img = current_img+1; // Increment current image number by one
            if(new_img > total_images){  // check if total has been reached
               new_img = 0;
            }
            $(this).attr('src','/path/some_image-' + new_img + '.gif'); // set new image source
 </script>
```

Please keep in mind that for this to work, the file and file path should only have one "-" in it or you'll have to split on a different unique character, and then name all the images with a number 0 - whatever after the "-" or the other character that you've chosen.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDzT8/

Answer (score 0):

The problem  in my case is pre-load images to cache. 
I can not user absolute position , becose  my parent element mixed positions and it bring images outside of parent element. I need to keep it simple.
Bu thanks for respond, i have found solution which working today.
I just before slide , duplicate  all used images on the page second time with 1px width so that will cache them to memory. Unfortunately all JavaScript pre-loads methods did not work